# Websphere cluster and multiple IHS servers - newbie - help needed

Tags: websphere, cluster-computing

We have an application running on 6 websphere 8.0 JVMs across 6 servers. There are 6 seperate IBM HTTP servers running on them as well. In our current setup - we have app deployed on WAS cluster and the plugin is configured in such a way to go across all systems. Is this over kill to have that may http servers? I am looking for recommendations.

Another question - is it possible to pair 1 jvm to 1 ihs instance for the same app. Meaning 6 pairs on jvm/ihs combo for the same app in one cluster? If possible, need guidance on how to set it up. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that these 6 servers are in one cluster.

> Is this overkill to have that may http servers?

Http server is not a very heavy process, so shouldn't impact performance greatly. How many servers - it depends on your application and number of users, but I usually go with 2 or 3 just to have high availability in case of problems and have them installed on separate boxes (not together with jvms).

> Another question - is it possible to pair 1 jvm to 1 ihs instance for the same app?

So you would like IHS to forward requests to only one machine, correct? Why would you like to do it? 
In that case your load balancer that distributes traffic to IHS must be more intelligent, because if you stop jvm connected to that IHS, the IHS will respond with 500 errors as there will be no other server to route requests. So you either need to always stop IHS first or load balancer will need to detect that and bypass that IHS.

In general, I wouldn't recommend that. To set it up, you would need to manually edit plugin-cfg.xml file for each pair, removing unwanted servers. And you will not be able to generate/propagate plugin config via console, when you deploy new apps, as each one need custom editing.